# Errors during GWT project export

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I am trying to export a GWT / Appengine project into an archive file or file system. getting the follow errors. I have not tried to import it into a different environment yet. Can you let me know if I am missing something. One other input which can help is - what is the best way to distribute development environment (during initial setup) between different developers for this kind of project. Obviously once it is setup have svn in place which can enable code sharing.

Problems were encountered during export:

```
  Error exporting Jetstream/gwt-unitCache/gwt-unitCache-00000138551F4486: File not found: D:\workspace\Jetstream\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-00000138551F4486.
    File not found: D:\workspace\Jetstream\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-00000138551F4486.
  Error exporting Jetstream/gwt-unitCache/gwt-unitCache-000001385521C520: File not found: D:\workspace\Jetstream\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-000001385521C520.
    File not found: D:\workspace\Jetstream\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache-000001385521C520.
  Error exporting Jetstream/war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Jetstream/war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml'.
    Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Jetstream/war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml'.
```

Comment: First of all, do you really need to export gwt-unitCache files which are generated during GWT compile? Second, your project seems to be out of sync with the file system. Just refresh your project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable automatic refresh in Preferences - General - Workspace - Refresh Automatically

In my case this didn't work for web.xml of Google App Engine. So I took the file individually in the eclipse navigator, refreshed it( by right clicking on the specific file and choosing 'refresh') and did the the archive export successfully.